# $http service in Factory returns undefined in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory, angularjs-http

I am new in angularJS and try to make a CRUD operation to clear my concept. I try to use angular factory but I google a lot and unable to find any solution on below concept. I just want to use my factory in controller which is not working for me.

Factory :

```
(function () {
'use strict';

 angular
.module('app', [])
.factory("crudFactory", function (path, myObj) {
     return {
         AddObject: function (path)
         {
             $http({
                 method: "POST",
                 url: path,
                 params: { myObj : myObj }
             }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
                 return response.data;
             }, function myError(response) {
                 return "Error Found :" + response.statusText;
             });
         },
         first: function () {
             return "";//
         }
     };
});
})();
```

I want to use this factory in controller but its not working.

Controller :

```
(function () {
'use strict';
debugger;
  angular
 .module('app')
 .controller('BusinessProfileCtrl', BusinessProfileCtrl);

function BusinessProfileCtrl($scope, crudFactory) {
    debugger;
    var vm = this; //vm = view model
    function Save() {
        debugger;
        var businessObj = {
            Id:vm.Id,
            Name: vm.Name,
        };
        var abc = crudFactory.AddObject("http://localhost:63358/BusinessUnit/Post", businessObj);
    }
    vm.Save = Save;
}
 })();
```

Hope will get any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "not working". What are you doing, what do you expect to happen, what happens instead? What do you expect the variable `abc` to contain, since AddObject doesn't return anything?

Comment: The $http POST method should use the `data` property for data, not `params`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in factory just return the http promise and from the controller catch that promise.

modify the factory like this;

```
.factory("crudFactory", function() {
    return {
        AddObject: function(path,myObj) {
            return $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: path,
                params: {
                    myObj: myObj
                }
            })
        },
        first: function() {
            return ""; //
        }
    };
});
```

in the controller catch the promise like this

```
var abc;
crudFactory.AddObject("http://localhost:63358/BusinessUnit/Post", businessObj).then(function mySuccess(response) {
    abc = response.data;
}, function myError(response) {
    abc = "Error Found :" + response.statusText;
});
```

Comment: bro "function BusinessProfileCtrl($scope, crudFactory) {}" is this syntax okay?

Comment: yeah its right although `factory("crudFactory", function (path, myObj) {` this is wrong. parameters should be removed. just updated the answer